# ActiveRecord + SQLite 3 behaves strangely

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

Using activerecord I made this query

```
AdImage.select("ad_images.id, ad_images.locale_id, ad_campaigns.click_url,
ad_campaigns.default_ad_image_id").joins("left outer join ad_campaigns on
ad_campaigns.id = ad_images.ad_campaign_id").where("ad_images.ad_campaign_id" => 1)
```

which generates the following sql query:

```
SELECT ad_images.id, ad_images.locale_id, ad_campaigns.click_url,
ad_campaigns.default_ad_image_id FROM "ad_images" left outer join ad_campaigns on
ad_campaigns.id = ad_images.ad_campaign_id WHERE "ad_images"."ad_campaign_id" = 1
```

and the result is the following:

```
 => [#<AdImage id: 22, click_url: "market://details?id=com.mobiata.flighttrack",
    locale_id: 2>]
```

which is wrong.

So I used ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute method to directly run the sql query:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ad_campaigns.click_url, ad_images.id, 
ad_images.locale_id, ad_campaigns.default_ad_image_id FROM ad_campaigns inner join
ad_images on ad_campaigns.id = ad_images.ad_campaign_id WHERE ad_images.ad_campaign_id = 1")
```

which returns the following:

```
[{"click_url"=>"market://details?id=com.mobiata.flighttrack", "id"=>22, "locale_id"=>2,
"default_ad_image_id"=>22, 0=>"market://details?id=com.mobiata.flighttrack", 1=>22,
2=>2, 3=>22}]
```

which has the strange repetition in it.

The only difference between the first and the second is "ad_images" vs ad_images in the table names.

My questions are:

1) I don't understand what makes this difference.

2) Why does the second query returns the garbage in SQLite3 while it doesn't happen in MySQL server?

Comment: I realized the first query has AdImage in the front so it is natural why it give AdImage columns only (AdImage and AdCampaign both have click_url, which I forgot and made me confused.) But the second question still needs an answer.

Comment: SQLite 3 seems to return results with index values and column names, I guess while MySql returns resultes with columns names only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I ended up with using "ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute" instead of using Rails' ActiveRecord helpers. There doesn't seem to be other solutions to it.
2. It turns out that you should use the index values instead of double quoted column names when you call values. Otherwise you will bump into Type errors when used in production with MySQL.